# Unable to add the webpart in web part page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, powershell, sharepoint-server

I am Unable to add the webpart in web part page in sharepoint 2013
below is the error message: 
An unexpected error has occurred. 
Technical Details

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 5ae3c39c-de1a-c087-6336-1fdd9aa8013d

Date and Time: 20/10/2014 11:00:13

-> tried with the powershell script
but it does not work either, no error is displayed in powershell command

Note that the same web part works on another virtual machine
kindly suggest what could be the possible solution for the same

thank you

Comment: Please check the credentialed error in 15 hive logs